# Use R to extract numeric values from string in a column

Tags: r, string, split

I have a table with the following column structure :

```
Name                                                Type
Urgent Care (Revenue Code: 0456)                    Per Case
IV Therapy (Revenue Codes 0260, 0269)               Per Visit
Oncology Treatment (Revenue Codes: 0280, 0289)      Per Visit
```

and I want to extract the numeric revenue codes from the names column so the table would look like :

```
Name                     Rev Code      Type
Urgent Care              0456          Per Case
IV Therapy               0260, 0269    Per Visit
Oncology Treatment       0280, 0289    Per Visit
```

the original data is inconsistent in the Name column as the word "Code" is followed by a ";" , blank space, "-" etc.  So I was trying to use regular expression to search for the first number and then split the column there.

I have tried using regex to search for the first digit and separate() from the tidyr package :

```
library(tidyr)
separate(mydata, Name, into = c("Name", "Rev Code"), sep = "[[:digit:]]")
```

which splits the column at the right location but the column "Rev Code" ends up blank?
I'm relatively new to R and would definitely appreciate any help!

#### Data:

```
structure(list(
Name = c("Urgent Care (Revenue Code: 0456)", "IV Therapy (Revenue Codes 0260, 0269)", 
"Oncology Treatment (Revenue Codes: 0280, 0289)"), 
Type = c("Per Case", "Per Visit", "Per Visit")), 
.Names = c("Name", "Type"), row.names = 1:3, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: agreed.  Just made that edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `extract`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, Name, into = c("Name", "RevCode"), "([^(]+)\\s*[^0-9]+([0-9].*).")

#               Name    RevCode      Type
#1        Urgent Care       0456  Per Case
#2         IV Therapy 0260, 0269 Per Visit
#3 Oncology Treatment 0280, 0289 Per Visit
```

As the OP commented that other patterns exist,

```
extract(df2, Name, into = c("Name", "RevCode"), "([^(]+)\\s*[^0-9]+([0-9].*).")
#                 Name         RevCode      Type
#1        Urgent Care             0456  Per Case
#2         IV Therapy       0260, 0269 Per Visit
#3 Oncology Treatment       0280, 0289 Per Visit
#4     Speech Therapy  0440-0444, 0449 Per Visit
```

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(Name = c("Urgent Care (Revenue Code: 0456)", 
 "IV Therapy (Revenue Codes 0260, 0269)", 
"Oncology Treatment (Revenue Codes: 0280, 0289)", 
"Speech Therapy (Revenue Codes: 0440-0444, 0449)"
), Type = c("Per Case", "Per Visit", "Per Visit", "Per Visit"
)), .Names = c("Name", "Type"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: That definitely helped.  There are couple rows in the data which leave the closing ")" in the RevCode column.  Couldn't figure out why.  Couple examples are :

Comment: Speech Therapy (Revenue Codes: 0440-0444, 0449)

Comment: @user6340762  The pattern is different there, as it also has `-`

Comment: @user6340762  I tested the same code with the new pattern and it is working fiine

Comment: you're right.  It is, my data had some white-space which I overlooked.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain which part of the regex denotes the separation of the columns "([^(]+)\\s*[^0-9]+([0-9].*)."  I understand the regex in isolation but not how it's separating the columns in the extract() function?

Comment: @user6340762  In the `extract`, we capture as a group.  So, whichever is inside the capture group (`(...)`) is the one got extracted. i.e. in the first case (`([^(]+)`) it is one or more characters that are not a `(` and in the second it is (`([0-9].*)`) it is number followed by other characters.

Answer (score 2):

```
read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=",", text='Name,Type
"Urgent Care (Revenue Code: 0456)", "Per Case"
"IV Therapy (Revenue Codes 0260, 0269)","Per Visit"
"Oncology Treatment (Revenue Codes: 0280, 0289)", "Per Visit"') -> df

library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

extract_codes <- function(x) {
  stri_match_all_regex(x, "[[:digit:]]+") %>% # extract the numbers
    map(~paste0(as.vector(.), collapse=", ")) # paste them back together
}

mutate(df, `Rev Code`=extract_codes(Name))
```

Answer (score 1):

Without extra package:

```
> data.frame(Name=gsub("\\(.*\\)", "", df$Name),
            RevCode=regmatches(df$Name, regexpr("[[:digit:]]+(\\,[[:space:]][[:digit:]]+)?", df$Name)),
            Type=df$Type)
                 Name    RevCode      Type
1        Urgent Care        0456  Per Case
2         IV Therapy  0260, 0269 Per Visit
3 Oncology Treatment  0280, 0289 Per Visit
```